# Spring No matching bean of type, expected at least 1 bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

Getting error

```
 No matching bean of type [foo.bar.service.AccountService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

my service:

```
public interface AccountService {

@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
```

**So I should get the implementation**

Where I am trying to get it :

```
public class CustomAuthentication implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;
```

In my other class also doing same thing, but there it works.

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;
```

When I remove the those 2 lines from my `CustomAuthentication`, getting no errors.

configuration just incase:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar" />
```

Comment: Do you have getters/setters for `AccountService`? if that so, try to put `@Autowired` to setter method. Your configureation _looks_ ok, but you don't post full classes and configs, so it difficult to say whats can be wrong here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only a spring managed object can Autowire another component/service/repository.

`public class CustomAuthentication implements AuthenticationProvider` need to be spring managed

like

```
@Controller
public class AccountController
```

Try annotating the CustomAuthenitcation with @Component

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthentication implements AuthenticationProvider
```

and let me know how CustomAuthentication Object is created. CustomAuthentication  object should be a proxy obtained by requesting to Spring(ApplicationContext.getBean() or autowired in another bean).

UPDATE:

reason for this error is you have two config files. spring-servlet.xml and spring-security.xml. Beans defined in spring-security.xml is not able to find those in other.

so you should try something like `<import resource="spring-servlet.xml"/>` in `spring-security.xml` .

Comment: I am defining the bean in my spring-security.xml : `<beans:bean id="customAuthentication" class="foo.bar.auth.CustomAuthentication"/>` , must I define it in spring-servlet.xml?

Comment: I added `@Service` or `@Component` there, but still same error.

Comment: I think you need to add  <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar" /> in spring-security.xml also

Comment: I had `<context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.auth" />` there, when I removed auth from there and put only `foo.bar` , getting error `BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0 : ` it does not make sense, I am expanding my component scan area and that produces errors .

Comment: reason for this error is you have two config files. spring-servlet.xml and spring-security.xml. Beans defined in spring-security.xml is not able to find those in other file

Comment: so you should try something like <import resource="spring-servlet.xml"/>    in spring-security.xml and remove component auto scan that we added in last  step

Comment: Yup that worked, BUT now it is reading everything twice, meaning it does all all hibernate stuff twice etc...so not very pretty.

Comment: can you explain.? is context initialization event fired twice?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20934/discussion-between-jaanus-and-subin-s)

Answer (score 0):

Please try `<context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.*" />`  or `<context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.service" />`. I believe it would work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write on AccountServiceImpl class @Service("accountService")